# 2 UITableViews -Table View Showing Files in Documents - Application Crashes on First Launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

This is my code for the UITableViews:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (tableView == _tblConnectedDevices){
        return [_arrConnectedDevices count];
    }
    if ([filePathsArray count] > 0){
        return [filePathsArray count];
    }
    return 1;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (tableView == _tblConnectedDevices){
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [_arrConnectedDevices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
    } else {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
        NSString *last = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSString *last2 = [[last lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
        cell.textLabel.text = last2;
        return cell;
    }

}
```

At first launch, with the app not installed on the device, the application will crash with this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

If I amend `-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{` to include:

```
    if ([filePathsArray count] == 0){
    return [filePathsArray count];
}
```

(I add the == 0 as well as > )
Then the app launches fine, but without displaying my UITableView correctly.
If I then close the app, and remove the added code, and launch it again, it works perfectly as expected.
What am I doing wrong/missing?
Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you specified where it crashes. However, this is an easy fix. Somewhere you're accessing index 0 of an empty array (aka index 0 doesn't exist). Don't be lazy and debug it line by line...

Comment: The problem is it doesn't tell me where it crashes @LordZsolt but I could tell its on the filePathsArray count line

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint. Then add normal breakpoints and see what happens at runtime.

Comment: I have used breakpoints also to check that is that line, and it is. @LordZsolt

Comment: No, it won't crash on that line, it crashes on `[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`

Comment: There, you really don't deserve it, but I posted an explanation why your code crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code crashes when you're trying to access your array:

```
NSString *last = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

The error clearly says: **index 0 beyond bounds for empty array**.

So it will crash when `indexPath.row` = 0, since the `numberOfRows` method is incorrect:

```
if ([filePathsArray count] > 0){
    return [filePathsArray count];
}
return 1;
```

This will return 1 when filePathsArray is empty. You should just drop the if and leave:

```
return [filePathsArray count];
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't at all mean to sound rude. I replied in a rush and its come across the wrong way. Thanks for your answer, but it still isn't working correctly. The tableview doesn't show what data is in my documents directory and the array remains empty without having the IF line?

Comment: Well most likely because you're filePathsArray is empty :|

Answer (score -1):

I'm looking some mistakes, for example you never pass this if:

```
if (tableView == _tblConnectedDevices){
    return [_arrConnectedDevices count];
}
```

You have to use isEqual: or compare tags...